# Django-admin-notifications error

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I would like to request assistance in this matter, I am using grappelli for my admin and I am trying to include an admin notification module via [Django-admin-notifications](https://github.com/andybak/django-admin-notifications/), I have followed every steps in the basic usage and I am getting an error that says:

`TemplateSyntaxError at /admin/
 notification_tag' is not a valid tag library: Template library notification_tag not found`

I am getting errors from `{% load notification_tag %}`.

I have followed the directions strictly(added `admin_notifications` in installed apps, imported `admin_notifications` in urls with `admin_notifications.autodiscover()`), What am i doing wrong?

Here's what it looks like(index.html of grappelli)

```
{% load notifications_tag %}
{% extends "admin/base_site.html" %}

<!-- LOADING -->
{% load i18n grp_tags log %}

<!-- JAVASCRIPTS -->
{% block javascripts %}
    {{ block.super }}
{% endblock %}

{% error_notifications %}

<!-- COLTYPE/BODYCLASS-- >
{% block bodyclass %}dashboard{% endblock %}
{% block content-class %}content-grid{% endblock %}

<!-- BREADCRUMBS -->
....
```

notifications.py:

```
import admin_notifications
from .models import boom
def notification():
    items = boom.objects.all()
    a = len(items)
    if a:
        return "You have " + str(a) + " items in models"

admin_notifications.register(notification)
```

Python 2.7, django 1.8.2

Comment: Can you show how your `notification.py` file looks like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your template you are trying to load `notifications_tag`:

```
{% load notifications_tag %}
```

or the name of the template tag file is `notification_tag`.
So, you should write

```
{% load notification_tag %}
```

whitout `s`.

Comment: I have been banging my head around to resolve this, many thanks!